# Not able to display/Convert Image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am new to Python and Opencv.
I am using the following code.

```
import Image
import ImageChops
im1 = Image.open("img1.png")
im2 = Image.open("img2.png")
diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1)
```

When I do `cv.ShowImage`, it asks me to convert it. I am trying all kinds of convert but there is always an error.
The only way I can see the image is by doing the following.

```
diff.save("final","JPEG")
```

Is there there another way I can convert to an IplImage or CvMat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv.SaveImage(diff, cv.LoadImage(diff))` might work, using the opencv function.

EDIT: In sight of the comment below, I think trying

```
cv.SaveImage(diff, cv.LoadImage(diff))
cv.ShowImage('box name', diff)
```

might work.

Comment: No.. I mean like, how can I display it in a box. For ex:
cv.ShowImage("box name",diff)

Answer (score 0):

The difference image contains negative pixel values, so I don't think cv.ShowImage can display it 'as is'.

The range of possible pixel values after subtraction is -255 to 255. You might want to normalize pixel values first, by

new_value = (old_value + 255)/2

I don't use OpenCV on Python, so I cannot post code for the above.